# undefined reference to with inheritance, makefile issue?

Tags: c++, inheritance, makefile

I am trying to compile a simple program that uses inheritance and I am running into this:

```
g++ -g -Wall -c q1Test.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -c figure.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -c rectangle.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -c triangle.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -o shapes q1Test.o figure.o rectangle.o triangle.o
q1Test.o: In function `main':
/home/aryner/school/fall2013/csc340/hw9/Q1/q1Test.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Figure::center()'
/home/aryner/school/fall2013/csc340/hw9/Q1/q1Test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Figure::center()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [shapes] Error 1
```

Searching this error leads me to believe I have a problem with my makefile but I am totally lost as to what that problem could be.  I have compared my makefile with some I have found online and I don't see why mine shouldn't work.  Here is the makefile I am using:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

default: shapes

shapes: q1Test.o figure.o rectangle.o triangle.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o shapes q1Test.o figure.o rectangle.o triangle.o

figure.o: figure.cpp figure.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c figure.cpp

rectangle.o: rectangle.cpp rectangle.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c rectangle.cpp

triangle.o: triangle.cpp triangle.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c triangle.cpp

q1Test.o: q1Test.cpp figure.h rectangle.h triangle.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c q1Test.cpp

clean:
        $(RM) shapes *.o *~
```

I don't want to post the source files because this is a homework assignment but I will give a brief description.  Figure is a superclass for rectangle and triangle.  Rectangle and triangle should be inheriting center() from figure.  q1Test is a test program that tests all the functions in triangle and rectangle, center is the only function tested that is inherited from figure and not overloaded.

Comment: Just for a quick check, try moving `q1Test.o` after `figure.o` in your `shapes:` rules.

Comment: Also, sanity check (although violating this would make another warning...), `center()` *does* have an implementation in `Figure` doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most likely cases are that you forgot to define `Figure::center()` in your source file or that you accidentally forgot to qualify them as `Figure::` so you're left with global `center` functions that aren't in the class.

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  I forgot to do Figure:: when implementing center().  I think I just saw that people where getting this error from mistakes in their makefiles and I got stuck looking at that. Thank you.